# Pegar elemento HTML via Javascript utilizando getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Qual o problema com esse código javascript? A função sempre retorna erro.

```
<!-- IMAGEM -->
<img class="coverPhotoImg photo img" src="ABC.JPG" alt="Foto 1">
<!-- IDENTIFICAÇÃO --->
<span class="hidden_elem enableFriendListFlyout outgoingButton" data-profileid="2015">Protocolo enviado.</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
//PELA LOGICA DEVERIA RETORNAR ABC.JPG
window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName('coverPhotoImg photo img').getAttribute('src'));
//PELA LOGICA DEVERIA RETORNAR 2015
window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName('hidden_elem enableFriendListFlyout outgoingButton').getAttribute('data-profileid'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `getElementsByClassName` sempre te retorna uma lista dos elementos que encontrou, mesmo que seja somente um, o código correto é:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("coverPhotoImg photo img")[0].getAttribute("src")
```